# How to launch combined app without seperation

Tags: android, android-activity

I've combined two apks. One of them runs only on background. So I thought that It must have been easy to do. But I have a problem. After I install my signed apk I see two of them on the menu. Why are they seperated? How can I make them run together? Here is the activity part which causes the problem.

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".FreeMemoryRecover">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining both of them as launcher activities, which is a perfectly legitimate thing to do, just not what you want.  Define only one as a launcher activity, and have it launch the other in a new task.

Note that you cannot launch an activity into the background, only launch an activity over the current one.  And there is no guarantee that an activity will continue to exist once it's in the background or even in the backstack of the same task.  It sounds like you should convert one of your activities to a `Service`.

Comment: Can't I use Broadcast Receiver for this? I want my first activity automatically start to when I run the second one. (I will only use the second launcher)

Comment: To receive what?  And again, you can never depend on more than one activity running at a time.

Comment: Understood. Can I convert activities to a service on the AndroidManifest.xml? I mean do I need to edit smali files for this?

Comment: @Soner You'd have to write a `Service` class.  Are you writing your app in Smali?  I've only used Smali for reverse engineering.